# Let's [cu]t this off!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I just came across the [cu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cu) tag.

There is no Wiki, so it is not defined what it is for.

It has only 8 questions, 0 followers.

It was used by the latest user for Cumulative Update.  Other users have used it for a cu file, the cu unix command, and a word press question about a custom field.

1. Unambiguous?  Obviously not
2. On topic? Maybe
3. Meaningful? No
4. Same thing in all common contexts? No

I doubt that are any "cu" experts.

Burn?

Comment: Since it has no sense and there are so few question I would just have edit it out (since you are above the 2k limit) and let it die.

Comment: *I am using* ***cu*** *utility to connect* - [How to redirect output of cu to a file ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29518760)

Comment: Dirty secret: low volume tags can be burned without consultation, as nobody will notice.

Comment: Is it worth keeping and editing the wiki to "Linux and Unix cu command"?  That seems the only genuine programming related.  Three question left with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tag no longer exists.  So this is now resolved.